# jQuery ajax Call upload File return json / text from C# ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, file-upload

I have a jquery ajax call that uploads a file of such:

```
            <input type="file" id="imgFileUpload" name="imgFileUpload"/>

            var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
            formData.append("imgFileUpload", $('#imgFileUpload').get(0).files[0]);

            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    url: myUrl,
                    data: formData,
                    success: function(data) {

                            alert(data);          //pops up "Object XMLDocument"
                            alert(data.d);        //pops up "undefined"

                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert("ERROR: " + err.responseText);
                    }
                });
```

I then searched for another solution, I've found that when you add the following to your ajax call:

```
dataType: 'text',
```

You get to receive a string back but now the returned string is XML-like, to be specific it returns the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      success
  </string>
```

**the thing is that I need only the string `success` itself**

Usually I have no problem with returning a string from C# to ajax but since in this scenario I am working with a `formData` I must define in my ajax call both : 
`processData` and `contentType` to be `false`.

In conclusion, I need to send an input file and return a string to the `success(data)`

Please help me conquer that flag... any help'd be much appreciated !!

Comment: try `alert($.trim($(data).text()));`.

Comment: Charlietfl - you should write your answer as a separte Answer so I could Accept it (that actually worked, thank you) :-)